# Что за тип верстки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

нашел на просторах интернета интересный сайт у которого при увеличении или уменьшении экрана расположение блоков не меняется. Я не могу понять, что это за тип верстки и как его сделать, в своем арсенале знаю только 4 типа верстки:

- Фиксированная
- Резиновая
- Адаптивная
- Отзывчивая

И адаптивность этого сайта по моему не подходит ни под один тип
Вот сайт: namalsk-rp.ru

То есть, при клике <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> ничего не меняется, но при открытии этого сайта на мобильных устройств, ну и там планшетов, все хорошо адаптируется.

Comment: вполне себе может быть на отступах и все, можешь скинуть, посмотрю

Comment: Большинство размеров на этом сайте прописано через `vh`, то есть зависит от высоты окна. При изменении масштаба высота окна не меняется, вот и внешний вид сайта тоже не меняется. А зацикливаться на терминах не вижу практического смысла

Comment: ссылка указана в теле вопроса

Comment: Это не тип верстки, а обычная дилетантская халтура. Нормально выглядит только на большом экране и мобильном... Ни одно нестандартное промежуточное разрешение не проработано.